# System.BadImageFormatException when compiled using any cpu

Tags: c#, badimageformatexception

When I compile the application using "Any CPU" I am getting `System.BadImageFormatException` whenever I try to open a connection using Firebird embedded dll (don't ask me why I am still using this legacy DB. not my choice)

Then I thought it must be that the dll only supports 32bit mode. So I tried to compile using x86 and indeed it runs fine this time.

However when I compile using x64 the application still runs fine. This confuses me cause it clearly indicates the dll is able to load in 64bit mode.

I made couple more tests and here are the results:

Any CPU: 64 bit process. System.BadImageFormatException
x86: 32 bit process. Runs fine
x64: 64 bit process. Runs fine
Any CPU (prefer 32bit): 32 bit process. Runs fine

I thought the only magic Any CPU does is that it picks whether to launch the process in 32/64 bit mode during startup. If the application runs fine under strict 64 bit mode then I would expect Any CPU to run fine on the same 64bit machine.

I would prefer to use Any CPU (without prefer 32bit flag) still since it makes the distribution easier.

What could be causing the exception and is there a way to deal with it?

Edit:
So I tried to use reflection to get assembly info and this is the error message I got

> Exception calling "GetAssemblyName" with "1" argument(s): "Could not
>   load file or assembly 'fbembed.dll' or one of its dependencies. The
>   module was expected to contain an assembly manifest." At line:1 char:1
>   + [reflection.assemblyname]::GetAssemblyName("${pwd}\fbembed.dll") | fl
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : BadImageFormatException

Comment: Check which image of the assembly is laded in each case. Is it the same image in 32 and 64 (I guess it is not as a 32bit image cannot be loaded in a 64bit process and vice versa). Also check the metadata on the offending assembly, IIRC there are .Net tools for that but you can use dotPeek or similar (there is an open source equivalent whose name I forget)

Comment: The name of the solution platform is not relevant to C# programs, architecture and bitness are determined at runtime and not build time.  Only the jitter preferences matter.  So always keep AnyCPU as the platform name, use Project > Properties > Build tab to override the default jitter choice.  "Prefer 32-bit" is what you prefer.

Comment: @HansPassant but Prefer 32-bit will launch the app in 32 bit mode even on a 64bit machine which is not what we want.

Comment: That's a very puzzling comment, given that you know that the dbase provider you use cannot operate in 64-bit mode.  I can't reverse-engineer that brain bug.

Comment: @HansPassant It works in 64-bit mode if I set the whole solution to 64bit. Its only the Any CPU that is giving me trouble.

Comment: @P.Kouvarakis I tried to use reflection to get assembly info for that dll and the error is shown above. Maybe the missing manifest is the reason?

Comment: I tried to explain that the solution platform name is not relevant at all, only the jitter overrides are important.  You **must** force your program to run in 32-bit mode, it is guaranteed to fail with BIFE if it doesn't.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204803/discussion-between-steve-and-hans-passant).

Comment: Just FIY: reflection won't help here. Reflection still loads the assembly just in a different special AppDomain. It still needs to load the assembly which will fail if bitness does not match

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After examining the dll's header it turns out that Nuget is the one performing the magic. If I set the target to x86/x64 nuget will include the according version of the dll during compile.

But if I target "Any CPU" nuget will pick the x86 version of the dll. Thus if I try to launch my application in 64 bit mode it will throw BIFE.

Comment: This is what I suspected, which is why I suggessted looking at the metadata. Anyway glad you figured it out.